# Rename a question mark (?) in filenames

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-10.04, rename, special-characters

With `rename` it is possible to bulk change filenames. I managed to get rid of all `+` with this command and replace them with underscores:

```
rename 's/\+/_/g' *
```

I could change normal letters like a to A with.

```
rename 's/a/A/g' *
```

but I could not rename the `?`, not like this `/\?` and not like this `/?`.

Is there any way to adress the "?" in the filename? Most FTP programs fail to rename files with `?` as well. Midnight Commander fails. The only way I found that works so far is:

```
mv ?myfile.txt myfile.txt
```

but this command is not flexible enough. I would prefer to bulk rename all `?` in all files.

Comment: I can remove files with true `?` without any trouble - just quote them as `rm "?.txt"`. Are you sure it is really `?` ? Maybe it is some binary character that is displayed by your shell as `?` ?

Comment: Can you indicate which `rename` tool it is that you are using (`rename --version`)? There are several different `rename` implementations out there.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what these file names look like? e.g., are the unknown characters always at the beginning of the filename?

Answer (score 6):

How about this:

```
for filename in *
do 
    if [ "$filename" == *"?"* ] 
    then
        mv "$filename" "$(echo $filename | tr '?' '-')" 
    fi
done
```

Or as a one liner:

```
for filename in *; do mv "$filename" "$(echo $filename | tr '?' '-')" ; done
```

However, it looks like your issue isn't that there are question marks in your filenames, but rather that your filenames contain characters that `ls` doesn't recognize.

Comment: Thanx for the fast reply.
is this a bash script?
I tried it as ubuntu bash and it did not change anything:

#!/bin/bash
for filename in $(ls | grep ?)
do 
    mv $filename $(echo $filename | tr '?' '-') 
done

Comment: one more thing that might be important:

if I list the directory with "ls"

the ? in the filenam eis displayed like this:

?%84nderung.pdf

but if I use "dir" it is displayed like this : \303%84nderung.pdf

I know the whole problem originates from a bad UTF-8 conversion. But maybe I have to search for "\303" instead of "?"

Comment: Don't do this ([Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs))!

Answer (score 5):

It's ugly, but here it goes, a one liner using Python:

```
python -c 'import os, re; [os.rename(i, re.sub(r"\?", "-", i)) for i in os.listdir(".")]'
```

As for cleaning up file names, maybe this will help you:

```
python -c 'import os, re; [os.rename(i, unicode(i, "utf-8", "ignore")) for i in os.listdir(".")]'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

```
for file in ./*;
do
  OUT=`echo $file | sed 's/\r//g'`;
  mv $file $OUT;
done
```

Apparently `\r` matches `?` in sed.

Comment: `\r` also matches `r`.

Answer (score 1):

The `?` char can be tricky to match. And i did not get lucky with `rename`. 
To avoid mismatches in encoding I found it easier to deal with the output of `dir`.

In my case the `?` then turns out to be a `\303\202`.
We still need to escape the `\` with another `\\`

Finally iterating over all files

```
for i in *; do mv $i $(echo $i | tr \\303\\202 _); done
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill but with the bash script in the link provided in this answer you can rename a filename with any characters in it including question marks, newlines, multibyte characters, spaces, dashes and any other allowable character:

https://superuser.com/a/858671/365691